# Node.js + Socket.io + Windows 7 / 8?

Tags: windows, node.js, socket.io

I've been searching everywhere, but can't seem to find a solution. Is it possible to install Socket.io on Node.js on Windows 7?

If not, is there some sort of alternative, or do you know of any future Windows support?

Usually the Node.js package manager is used, however I can't find a way of installing that on Windows. http://npmjs.org/

I'm currently using Node.exe (not running it through Cygwin).

This is how I'd imagine it would be installed on Windows, if NPM worked:

```
npm install socket.io
```

## Node Package Manager now works on Windows 7

Simply install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.10/node-v0.6.10.msi) and type `npm install socket.io` into the Windows console and look in `C:\Users\[insert username]\node_modules`.

Comment: If you have enough memory, it could be a good idea to use VirtualBox with Ubuntu as a guest OS.

Comment: @user482594 I've recently tried that it it's actually quite good. However Node version 0.6.0 works very well on Windows 7, and i'm now using it. http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.0/node.exe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am confirming that npm **install socket.io** works perfectly with Node.js 0.6.10 on Windows 7 (remember to run **cmd** as Administrator).

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is having trouble getting Node.js and socket.io working on Windows...

There is the nodejs-win project on Google Code.

http://code.google.com/p/nodejs-win/downloads/detail?name=node_setup_0.5.6.7.exe&can=2&q=

And here is a video that shows the basics of using it.

*[Node.JS & Socket.IO Chat System in Windows](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pyipKHsTqWc)*

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. However I've installed Ubuntu and overcome all of the problems I was having in Windows. However I'd rather develop on Windows as Ubuntu doesn't support my laptops i7 onboard graphics so I can't use dual monitors :(((!

Comment: [Google Code is shutting down](https://opensource.googleblog.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html). You may want to update before it is too late.

Answer (score 4):

Now that Node.js version 0.6.0 is available, and it seems pretty stable so far, I'm going to suggest using it if you're planning on developing on Windows.

http://nodejs.org/download/

Answer (score 2):

Either use a Linux box or `git clone` the socket.io repository and `require` it from a local path.

You will have to copy the entire socket.io library into, for example, `lib/socket.io/`

Then `var io = require("./lib/socket.io/index.js`

Comment: @JackBrown you will have to manually include socket.io-client and change the references in your socket.io code

Comment: Do you know where I can download socket.io-client, it doesn't seem to be in the latest distributable on github.

Answer (score 2):

npm runs on Node.js. If you are having problems running npm, then you should also be having problems with Node.js. Assuming you are running Node.js through Cygwin, then you should be able to run

> ```
> node npm install socket.io
> ```

*(Which is the same as npm install socket.io)*

Also.

Npm is just the Node.js package manager. There is nothing that it provides that you can't get from the repositories themselves. It is just, for obvious reasons, a lot easier to use npm.

If you want the socket.io included, then just create a node_modules directory inside of your `/lib` directory or wherever your project is, and then clone the socket.io to it.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io

---

### Edit

The OP indicated that he is using node.exe. There is no way currently as of 1st September 2011 to use npm with node.exe. It is currently on the node.exe roadmap and will hopefully be completed soon, but not as of today.
(Check the mailing list if you want to be updated).

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, i'm running Node.exe

Comment: @Layke I believe npm support for windows will come before christmas

Answer (score 1):

Since the 0.6.6 version (as far as I remember) Node.js has a normal version for Windows, and after installing it a npm.exe file appears in the install directory, not sure how exactly I was running it, maybe something like `node npm install socket.io`.

Or maybe `npm install socket.io`. If none of these works, try to execute npm by typing full path to it (unless you have added a system variable for the path). For the record - I have successfully installed sokcet.io on Windows 7 via npm :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, downloading the modules directly from GitHub and putting them in the "node_modules" directory works. AFAIK that's what npm does. It works both if you put it in your user directory, or in the same directory as node.exe.

Too bad there's no Windows port for npm, since there's almost no porting needed to be done, and that node comes as a stand-alone executable instead of an installer, like Python.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but I really like using Node.exe on Windows. Quite simple to just drag and drop the .js server file on to the executable, and then it's up and running!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and edited the Socket.IO library to work on windows. Details of the same you can find [here](http://mindofaprogrammer.blog.com/2011/11/06/socket-io-library-for-node-js-on-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

Until NPM is built for Windows you'll need to download the packages manually and create the node_modules folder structure in the node.exe folder.  Follow [this post](http://www.sematopia.com/2011/11/getting-socket-io-to-run-on-windows-node-js-setup/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `package.json` in your project directory with the following.

```
{
     "name": "project name",
     "description": "project description,
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "dependencies": {
        "express": "2.4.6",
        "socket.io": "version"
     }
}
```

Then run the npm install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Node.js v10.22 on Windows 7 - this worked for me:

```
npm install socket.io@0.8.4
```