# Socket.IO sample compatible with .Net

Tags: .net, wcf, node.js, push-notification, socket.io

I need a Hello World! sample of socket.IO running on windows.
Client: HTML, JavaScript
Server: able to connect to .Net
Have you seen such a sample?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js and Socket.io should run on windows straight out of the box. Node.js should be able to communicate with your .Net server locally or remotely.

Here is an old question of mine regarding running Node and Socket.IO on Windows 7.
[Node.js + Socket.io + Windows 7 / 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274442/node-js-socket-io-windows-7)

This question should answer any questions on having the two communicate:
[Communicating between Node.Js and ASP.NET MVC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091031/communicating-between-node-js-and-asp-net-mvc-application)